# Android Settings java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when integrating Xposed

Tags: java, android, xml, settings

I've been working on an Android ROM for about a month now, and one of my goals was to integrate Xposed framework into the stock Settings app. I built in the Setting, and made the layouts, but for some reason, I always get a force-close if I click on any of the menus. The logcat is as follows.

```
    D/SubSettings( 1570): Launching fragment com.android.settings.xposed.Framework
    W/dalvikvm( 1570): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/android/settings/xposed/util/AssetUtil;
    D/AndroidRuntime( 1570): Shutting down VM
    W/dalvikvm( 1570): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4157ace0)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570): Process: com.android.settings, PID: 1570
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at com.android.settings.xposed.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:44)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:590)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner(PreferenceActivity.java:1183)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader(PreferenceActivity.java:1199)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:545)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at com.android.settings.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:213)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    at com.android.settings.xposed.util.AssetUtil.<clinit>(AssetUtil.java:18)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 1570):    ... 23 more
    W/ActivityManager(  801):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.SubSettings
    W/ActivityManager(  801):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.SubSettings
```

I've looked at Framework.java at line 44 and AssetUtil.java at line 18 and still can't figure out the errors. What's more interesting is that de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.java doesn't even exist.

My source is here: https://github.com/Primed/android_packages_apps_Settings

Any help is appreciated, thank you!